# Need help with CSS & JQuery for Twitter like dropdown login box

Tags: php, jquery, css

I am currently designing a 'Sign In'  dropdown much like Twitter login dropdown. You can see the current progress of it at http://mashup2.sunnydsouza.com/index3.php

As you can see there, for some reason, there are certain css issues because of which am not exactly the same effect as shown in this tutorial http://aext.net/example/twitterlogin/#

Am not sure where am going wrong in this css (front.css) file. Is there some over-riding issues?

I want the same exact effect as shown in the example site.

On another note, also, am using JQuery validation plugin to check whether the username/pass fields are entered before clicking submit. What I want is that if a user enters an incorrect username/password, the error login message should come within the dropdown itself, without reloading the entire page again

But when user enters correct username/password, the page would refresh and the 'Sign In'  would now replace with the username of the user entered (that will a dropdown too, with Control panel,logout options etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems is because in your stylesheet you say #topnav {...} but in your HTML topnav is assigned as a class, not an ID. None of the #topnav styles are being applied.

Comment: yes Collin, you were right...silly mistake from my side. Anyways any idea on the jQuery side of my question? Hey also, if yous till see my site, for some reason the sign in and the dropdown box seems broken. There arent connecting together :( Why is this happening?

Comment: You can fix the display of the dropdown by changing the width in the css and making the inputs a bit smaller so it all lines up with the right edge of the sign-in link. You can also decrease the 'top' property in the css a bit so the dropdown covers the rounded edges of the button.

Comment: For the validation you'll want to define a 'remote' property for your validation rule and just inject the error message in to the dropdown when there are errors. It's better if you just read through the docs instead of me trying to explain it all here, there are a lot of good examples: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation